# A PHP Error was encountered (trying to upload .json file into webpanel in my database)

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting these errors when trying to upload a .json file to my webserver/webpanel:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given
>
> Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php
>
> Line Number: 1113
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
>
> Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php
>
> Line Number: 1114
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php
>
> Line Number: 1144

Here is the code:

```
    /**
 * The "set_insert_batch" function.  Allows key/value pairs to be set for batch inserts
 *
 * @param   mixed
 * @param   string
 * @param   boolean
 * @return  object
 */
public function set_insert_batch($key, $value = '', $escape = TRUE)
{
    $key = $this->_object_to_array_batch($key);

    if ( ! is_array($key))
    {
        $key = array($key => $value);
    }

    $keys = array_keys(current($key));
    sort($keys);

    foreach ($key as $row)
    {
        if (count(array_diff($keys, array_keys($row))) > 0 OR count(array_diff(array_keys($row), $keys)) > 0)
        {
            // batch function above returns an error on an empty array
            $this->ar_set[] = array();
            return;
        }

        ksort($row); // puts $row in the same order as our keys

        if ($escape === FALSE)
        {
            $this->ar_set[] =  '('.implode(',', $row).')';
        }
        else
        {
            $clean = array();

            foreach ($row as $value)
            {
                $clean[] = $this->escape($value);
            }

            $this->ar_set[] =  '('.implode(',', $clean).')';
        }
    }

    foreach ($keys as $k)
    {
        $this->ar_keys[] = $this->_protect_identifiers($k);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: just use `$keys = array_keys($key);`

Comment: `current($key)` returns value so, in that situation `array_keys()` function fails because `array_keys()` accept either array or array and value as argument while you are specifying value only....